# Chain of trust cannot be added in VBA code

Tags: vba, ssl, certificate, code-signing

I received a .pfx Code Signing certificate from Sectigo CA.
After I installed it, I signed my VBA Code with said certificate.

When I open the file on a different computer, it can't be verified that it's signed and when I look into the certificate details, it doesn't display me the chain of trust like on the computer I signed it on.
Is there a way I can add the chain of trust to my vba code?

[image: Certificate details on computer I signed it]
[image: Certificate details on testing computer]